# onDestroy() won't get called after this.finish()

Tags: android, milestone

I'm wondering why the Motorola Milestone with 2.1-update1 behaves differently from the Emulator or e.g. the Nexus One. I am trying to exit my app with:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(mayDestroyActivity) this.finish();
    super.onPause();
}
```

This works well on either Emulator or Nexus One. `onDestroy()` gets called immediatly after `onPause()` and `onStop`. But not for the Milestone. Instead, `onDestroy()` gets called when another Activity is started. Its section in the Manifest looks like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"  
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"  
 android:label="@string/questionnaire_item"
 android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
 <intent-filter>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
 </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Does anyone have a hint on this? My app depends on exiting properly since I save all progress in `onDestroy()`

Thanks,
Steff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user exits to the home screen this does not need to mean that the app should be exited. In most of the time it will give a better user experience if the app just goes to the background. Try to rely on saveInstanceState and onPause.

Exiting a app is seen as bad practice in the android world, featuring a phone with a good system for true multitouch can get better user experience if the app keeps running after pressing the home screen.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. The Milestone's different behavior made me finally see things the right way. Strange but funny and useful...

Answer (score 5):

You are doing it wrong. This is what the Doc says:

> Note: do not count on this method
>   being called as a place for saving
>   data! [...] There are situations where
>   the system will simply kill the
>   activity's hosting process without
>   calling this method (or any others) in
>   it, so it should not be used to do
>   things that are intended to remain
>   around after the process goes away.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29

Comment: You're right, my approach is wrong. But anyhow, I want my app to pass onDestroy() when the user exits to the home screen.

Comment: There is no way to do the wrong approach right. "There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method" is a statement you should take literally.

Comment: You're right again. I moved everything to onPause(). Works as well. Thanks

Comment: @stfn thanks for mentioning onPause(). I also had this issue and moved finish() from onStop() to onPause() and now onDestroy() is called.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `onSaveInstanceState`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state) link.